# I can't display the $key value from Firebase in angular 5

Tags: angular

i have some issues I can't display the $key value from Firebase in angular 5
i get all the other value but the $key i can't display it

Here are the code of my service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Employee } from '../Employee';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {

  employees: AngularFireList<any[]>;
  Employee: AngularFireObject<any>;

  constructor( 
    public af: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { 
    this.employees = this.af.list('/employees/employees') as AngularFireList <Employee[]>;
  }
getEmployees(): AngularFireList <any> {
  return this.employees ; 
}
}
```

And this is my component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from '../../services/employee.service';
import { Employee } from '../../Employee';
import { all } from 'q';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css']
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {

  employees : Employee [][];
  constructor(public employeeService : EmployeeService ) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeService.getEmployees().valueChanges().subscribe( employees => {
      this.employees = [employees[0]] ;
     
      
      console.log(this.employees);
      
    })
  }

}
```

and this is the interface with all variables

```js
export interface Employee{

    $key?:string;
    firstName?:string;
    lastName?:string;
    email?:string;
    country?:string;
    city?:string;
    phone?:number;
    salary?:number;
}
```

and finally the html code to display data

```html
    <tr *ngFor="let item of employees">
      
      <th >{{item.firstName}}</th>
      <th >{{item.lastName}}</th>
      <th >{{item.email}}</th>
      <th >{{item.country}}</th>
      <th >{{item.city}}</th>
      <th >{{item.phone}}</th>
      <th >{{item.salary}}</th>
      <th >{{item.$key}}</th>

    </tr>
```

I don't know how to get a reference to the key

Comment: 1) why do you use `$` as thats for jquery? 2) on the fact you put `$key?:string;` you dont have to have a value for it, its optional

Comment: I test it with $ and without it but still the same problem can't display the value

Comment: are you sure it has a value in the database? or from the service you get it from?

Comment: Yes im sure this from firebase 

"-Muh_aSRah7kJewq8C29" : {
      "firstName" : "Name1",
      "lastName" : "Name2",
      "email" : "Name1@gmail.com",
      "country" : "country1",
      "city" : "la",
      "phone" : "123-456-7890",
      "salary" : "10000.00"

Comment: well im not sure, theres no `key` property within that object

Comment: where is the `key` value within the data object you posted?

Comment: This is the key by default in firebase
 -Muh_aSRah7kJewq8C29

Comment: no, thats the object's name/property name. it may be an UUID within firebase but thats just a property name in terms of json

Comment: if you want the key, you either need to somehow read the property name or save the key within the data object itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here.
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md

The code in component became

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeService.getEmployees().snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(action => ({ key: action.key, ...action.payload.val() }));
    }).subscribe( employees => {
      this.employees = [employees[0]];
      console.log(this.employees);
      
    })
  }
```

After that you need to remove the "$" symbole from the interface and html file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way in the component.ts. / Note that I have selected snapshotChanges().
then only you can access the key value.

```
items:Observable<any>;
constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase){
this.items = db.list('person').snapshotChanges() ;
```

then via HTML we can access the key value

```
*ngFor="let item of items | async ">
Item key value is :  {{item.key}}
```